# Excel, vba, and onedrive or sharepoint file sharing

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint, onedrive

I have two local excel files on my hard drive. Both have Macros to achieve certain goals. But after all being done the end result is that after i click a command button from one excel file (lets call it 'A') the data gets transferred based on a macro behind that command button to the other file (let call this one 'B') in a certain format.

All this works great. The source file 'A' is accessible by everyone to enter data, but the destination file to maintain data integrity is read only but a macro is able to write into it. For obvious reasons, both file are on a shared folder so data can be entered one file and transferred to another by everyone.

Now I want to be able to continue with the same functionality but now on a sharepoint or onedrive. Unfortunately I am unable to do so.

Comment: Your desperation sustains me.

Comment: Why specifically are you unable to do so?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! As you may have skipped the intro, your question is lacking a great amount detail necessary to provide a solution. What are you trying to accomplish and where are you running into issues? For more info, check out [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are your exact requirements, however I think you can use SharePoint lists with SPD workflows to meet your requirements instead of using excels.

Whenever business users need data in excel they can always export them from list.

There is one more easy way where you can let users enter data in excel however it will be stored in SharePoint list.